# Active Record Callbacks stopped working consistently after upgrading to Rails 5

Tags: ruby, callback, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently upgraded an app from Rails 4.2 to 5.2. This app includes several active record callbacks, where the user enters a value or clicks a button and a callback is issued to continue on with the program. After the upgrade, these callbacks are no longer working consistently in production. Locally things work fine, but once deployed (using capistrano) it regularly takes 3-6 tries to get a callback to go through. Here is my callback class:

```
module CallAfterCommit
  def self.included(base)
    base.after_commit :notify_commit # piggyback off active_record hook.
    base.include(InstanceMethods)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  ##
  # Instance methods for CallAfterCommit mixin.
  module InstanceMethods
    ##
    # Takes a callback that will be called whenever any instance of this model with the same id is committed. The instance
    # this method is called on must have an id set.
    def add_after_commit_callback(&block)
      raise "#{self} does not have an id yet, so it could not add callback" if id.nil?

      self.class.add_after_commit_callback(id, &block)
    end

    ##
    # Removes instances of callback to be called when a model with this id is committed.
    def remove_after_commit_callback(callback)
      self.class.remove_after_commit_callback(id, callback)
    end

    ##
    # Returns true if the callback is registered for the model's id, and returns false otherwise.
    def after_commit_callback?(callback)
      self.class.after_commit_callback?(id, callback)
    end

    private

    def notify_commit
      self.class._notify_commit(id)
    end
  end

  ##
  # Class methods for CallAfterCommit mixin.
  module ClassMethods
    ##
    # Add a callback to a set of callbacks for the given id. to be called after any instance with that id is committed.
    # Returns the callback as a proc, which can be used to remove the after commit callback
    def add_after_commit_callback(id, &block)
      raise ArgumentError, "Cannot add callback. No record of id #{id} exists for #{self}." unless exists?(id)
      raise ArgumentError, "Cannot add callback. Callback already exists for #{id}." if after_commit_callback?(id, block)

      registered_callbacks[id] ||= []
      registered_callbacks[id] |= [block]

      block
    end

    ##
    #  Removes the callback for a given id. Raises an error if the callback cannot be removed.
    def remove_after_commit_callback(id, callback)
      raise "Could not remove callback because it is not registered for id #{id}" unless after_commit_callback?(id, callback)

      registered_callbacks[id].delete(callback)
      # Remove the hash entry to the empty array, so we don't collect every id ever listened to.
      registered_callbacks.delete(id) if registered_callbacks[id].empty?
    end

    ##
    # Returns true if the callback is registered for the given id, and returns false otherwise.
    def after_commit_callback?(id, callback)
      !registered_callbacks[id].nil? && registered_callbacks[id].include?(callback)
    end

    ##
    #  Execute all the callbacks registered for this id.
    def _notify_commit(id)
      registered_callbacks[id]&.each(&:call)
    end

    private

    ##
    # Returns a hash of ids to an array of callbacks
    def registered_callbacks
      # hash of ids to an array of callbacks
      @registered_callbacks ||= {}
    end
  end
end
```

And here is one of the places that uses said callback:

```
module WaitForUserSimple
  def self.included(base)
    base.after_initialize :setup_new_instance, if: :new_record? # piggyback off active_record hook.
  end

  ##
  # Receive message from the user. Expects params to have a key for :user_choice and looks for 'ok' or 'quit'
  def receive_user_data(params)
    logger.info 'received user data'
    details.user_choice = params[:user_choice]
    details.save!
  end

  def stop
    logger.info 'Stopping simple user step'
    receive_user_data(user_choice: 'quit')
  end

  private

  def setup_new_instance
    # We need this detail when we initialize, because we watch it when waiting for the user.
    self.details ||= SimpleUserStepDetail.new(test_step: self)
  end

  def run_test_step
    event = Concurrent::Event.new # Use this to let us know if there has been a save since we reloaded the details.

    callback = details.add_after_commit_callback do
      logger.info("Callback called. Setting event for #{self}")
      event.set
    end

    while details.reload.user_choice.nil?
      logger.info("#{self} waiting for details to be saved")
      event.wait
      event.reset
      logger.info("#{self} notified that event was saved. Checking details.")
    end

    details.remove_after_commit_callback(callback)
    logger.info("Got user choice: #{details.user_choice}")
    details.user_choice == 'ok'
  end
end
```

There are no error messages or logging statements to show what is going on. Does anyone have any suggestions on what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a problem with puma workers. I set puma_workers to 1 in my deploy.rb file, and now everything is working fine.